# Parameter value truncated from second word onwards in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I am calling a function in `commonfuncs` to send email as below:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/ksh
. commonfuncs
emailsend 'test mail' 'body of the mail' 'abc.efg@domain.com'
```

the function is as below:

```sh
function emailsend
{
    esubject=$1
    etext=$2
    etolist=$3  
    efromid="from.id@domain.com"

    echo $etext >email.txt
    cat email.txt | mailx -r $efromid -s $esubject $etolist
}
```

The email is sent fine. But the subject is send only as `test` instead of `test mail`. Tried with double quotes too but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap with double quotes parameters of the `malix` command:

```
cat email.txt | mailx -r "$efromid" -s "$esubject" "$etolist"
```

because the `space` character is a delimiter of the command line arguemnts.